# Minimum of a negative value

Tags: mathematics, word-meaning

What is the best way to call the smallest value (absolute value, |x|) of x if all x are negative?

If we call it minimum, then it could be meaning the biggest absolute value...

Addendum:

I am looking for a suitable name for my variable in the code I am writing.

Comment: Usually there is precedence in the operators so MIN(ABS(**X**)) would give you the generalised solution for the smallest absolute value (largest negative **X**, smallest positive **X**).   ABS(MAX(**X**)) would be the case for only negative numbers.

Comment: @Peter isn't he only asking for terminology ?

Comment: If you're speaking about values of |x|, then it's fine to say **the minimum value of |x|**. If you're speaking about values of x, you should use **magnitude** as in apsillers' answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer... I am looking for a suitable name for the variable that I want to create.

Comment: From [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html): `min_mag`(x, y): Compares the values numerically with their sign ignored. -- By the way, I don't think a variable name in your code is really on-topic.

Answer (score 11):

In a formal mathematics setting, you would say you want the number with the **smallest [*magnitude*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics))**. For real numbers, *magnitude* is the number's distance from zero on the number line. You could also say you want the number with the **smallest absolute value**, but that's slightly longer to say.

Other notes:

- Using "minimum" is incorrect, since for real numbers, "minimum" means "leftmost on the number line" -- so, in your case, the negative number with the *largest* magnitude is the minimum.
- Using "smallest" for negative numbers causes ambiguity about whether you mean "smallest magnitude" or "lowest value" (i.e., leftmost on the number line).

Comment: If we're being pedantic, shouldn't that be "lowest magnitude" and not "smallest magnitude?"

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi You're probably right, since magnitude appears to be a value's position in an ordering. (I haven't done much advanced math recently.) I'll double-check tomorrow and edit accordingly.

Comment: please don't let that detract from your excellent answer, though :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I'd call it the **closest value to zero**. Its meaning is clear and unambiguous, and it's less likely to scare off non-technical people than words like 'magnitude'.

Answer (score 1):

```
-1, -2, -3, -4
```

- In technical terms, -4 is the **most negative** number, and -1 is the **least negative** among these numbers.[[most negative](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3b63x-0P3_UC&pg=PA94&dq=%22most+negative+number%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-punJ0cDLAhVGJpQKHXrLBd0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22most%20negative%20number%22&f=false) in google books, and [least negative has max value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942561/2204022)]
- for the sake of completion, -1 is **less negative** than -3, and -4 is **more negative** than -2. [[See the answer to *1.G*](http://ae.edugain.com/pdf/samples/grade-6-Integers-smaller-than-greater-than-ae.pdf), and [this in google book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2o4_G0PRIQMC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=%22less+negative+number%22&source=bl&ots=4IO-MRtOEC&sig=K2M8lzDbdOeQmBlpISNT1tHj8ZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfze7cz8DLAhUFEpQKHU7QDpUQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=%22less%20negative%20number%22&f=false)]

Specifically, to answer your question, if all x are negative then the x with `min(abs(x))` is **the least negative**.

Comment: Why downvoted ?